# Using variable as a key in an bash associative array

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, associative-array

I'm trying to read the English dictionary in Linux into an associative array, using the words as keys and and predefined string as a value. This way I can look up words by key to see if they exist. Also I need all to words to be lowercase. It's fairly simple but the bash syntax is getting in my way. When I run the code below, I get a 'bad array subscript' error. Any thoughts as to why that might be ?

```
 function createArrayFromEnglishDictionary(){
        IFS=$'\n'
        while read -d $'\n' line; do
            #Read string into variable and put into lowercase.
            index=`echo ${line,,}`
            englishDictionaryArray[$index]="exists"
            done < /usr/share/dict/words
            IFS=$' \t\n'
    }
```

Comment: `IFS=$' \t\n'` is the same as `unset IFS`.

Comment: What is the syntax `${VAR,,}`? I've never seen this before, and can't find any references elsewhere

Comment: <code>${VAR,,}</code> means lowercase in Bash.

Answer (score 6):

I think following example will help..

```
$ declare -A colour
$ colour[elephant]="black"
$ echo ${colour[elephant]}
black

$ index=elephant
$ echo ${colour["$index"]}
black
```

Answer (score 5):

`$index` is empty at some point. You also have a rather [totally pointless use of echo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140415205935/http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo) assuming you wanted the line verbatim and not whitespace compressed. Just use `index="${line,,}"`.

Comment: index="${line,,}" didn't work, but I don't know why. I had tried this before and expected it to work. Should the key-value assignment be any different from what it is like now ?

Comment: It seems to work now, I changed englishDictionaryArray[$index]="exists" to englishDictionaryArray["${index}"]="exists" at first, that didn't work. And of course, the error was completely unintuitive, I had to add spaces at both sides of ". so  [ "${index}" ] works. Man I hate bash sometimes.

Comment: So don't use bash for these things. There are many other, more suitable scripting languages for this kind of advanced string juggling-and-manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

To use associative arrays in bash, you need bash version 4, and you need to declare the array as an associative array with `declare -A englishDictionaryArray`

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Combining your work and other answers, try this:

I'm using GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A DICT
function createDict(){
    while read LINE; do
        INDEX=${LINE,,}
        DICT[$INDEX]="exists"
    done < /usr/share/dict/words
}

createDict

echo ${DICT[hello]}
echo ${DICT[acdfg]}
echo ${DICT["a's"]}
```

Comment: @Daniel Kuta, 6 years later and it still seems to work for me. This does not help you, but perhaps you can provide error messages and output and version of bash?

Comment: Note that `/bin/bash` on macOS is bash version 3.2, which does not support associative arrays.

Mac users could install and use latest bash from e.g. homebrew.

Comment: For those who don't know `${LINE,,}` will return a lowercase version of `$LINE`